# (How) should I ask for a big list of references on several TeX-related topics?

Tags: discussion

Would a [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) of references of all kind of TeX-related topics be useful, and if so, how should it be asked?

I'm thinking in something like

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)
- [What are good advanced LaTeX books?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/what-are-good-advanced-latex-books)
- [How to write a LaTeX class file for my thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51865/5872)

But with CW answers covering every kind of topics, with every kind of references (books, book chapters, articles, blog posts, screencasts, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posts you linked to are very close to being "not a real question" because they are very broad and usually they were asked after some discussion, and every time such a post appears, it's possible closure is discussed in the community.

I believe that a question with even broader scope would be closed after such discussion. StackExchange doesn't like broad questions in general.

Comment: I agree. The general uneasiness about a huge "big list" question like this is mirrored in the highly untypical lack of responses to this meta-question. Nobody could really say "No, don't do this because xyz", but nobody seemed to be a big fan either.